# pjsip vs linphone for iOS

Tags: ios, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm building an iPhone app that provides voice and possibly video at some future time between the users of the app.  There's no need for calling out into the PBX world.  I've searched a little on the webs and linphone and pjsip seem to be the most actively developed SIP libraries available to me.  Can anyone comment on which one might be a better choice for this application?